# why model posted to action Display in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

have 2 action with same name.(AddNewUser) one of them work with HttpGet and another with HttpPost.

```
[HTTPGet]
 public ActionResult AddNewUser()
    {
        User user = Utilities.SessionProvider.GetCurrentUser();
        if (user.ID_User == 0)
            return Redirect("Apps.kosarfci.ir");

        RoleType role = (RoleType)RoleDeterminer.RoleDeterminate();

        if (role != RoleType.Center)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Restriction");
        }

        return View("VNewUser");
    }




 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewUser(VMNewUser InModel)
    {
        User user = Utilities.SessionProvider.GetCurrentUser();
        if (user.ID_User == 0)
            return Redirect("Apps.kosarfci.ir");

        RoleType role = (RoleType)RoleDeterminer.RoleDeterminate();

        if (role != RoleType.Center)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Restriction");
        }
        IUserBL centerUserBL = new CenterUserBL();

        InModel.User.UserName = InModell.User.NationalCode;
        InModel.User.Password = InModell.User.PersonalCode;
        bool confirmedBL = centerUserBL.AddUser(InModel.User);

       _msgList.Add(new Message() { MsgType = MessageType.Success, MsgContent =         MessageProvider.GetMessage(MessageContent.Submit_Success_NewUser) });
        ViewBag.Message = _msgList;

        return View("VNewUser");

    }
```

AddNewUser() ,return a form with input entry and then form submited to AddNewUser(VMNewUser InModel). but after that a form with filled entry with posted model is displayed. i expect that a form with blank input entry display because i dont send pre-filled model(VMNewUser) in to the view.
why?

--VMNewUser--

@model PersonManagement.Views.User.VMNewUser

```
<style>
    table{
        font-family:Tahoma;
    }
</style>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewUser", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.User.FirstName)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>family</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.User.LastName)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>personalcode</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.User.PersonalCode)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>nationalcode</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.User.NationalCode)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="create" style="font-family:Tahoma;float:left" /></td>

        </tr>

    </table>

}
```

Comment: After posting it to the model and saving, redirect the user to the AddNewUser(Httpget) or call "return RedirectToAction("AddNewUser")" at the end of AddNewUser(HttpPost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for sending back the populated model is to prevent the user from having to re-populate the form if there is an error processing the request server-side. It also provides the client with information about what fields failed and if there are any particular error messages that should be displayed.

It's recommended you use the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) therefore if the request *is* successful, you would redirect the user to a new page. In your case, you could redirect the user back to `AddNewUser` action which would present the user with the empty form again e.g.

```
return RedirectToAction("AddNewUser");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1:**

In your **HttpPost** method return to **Action** instead of returning view  like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("AddNewUser");
```

**Way 2:**

or simply `return View()` without passing **Model** object which means `null` model and the fields will not be populated obviously:

```
return View();
```

**Way 3 :**

you can also do like this, if **Model** is valid save data and return **View** with empty fields, otherwise return view with populated data to user.

Like this :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewUser(VMNewUser InModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
        User user = Utilities.SessionProvider.GetCurrentUser();
        if (user.ID_User == 0)
            return Redirect("Apps.kosarfci.ir");

        RoleType role = (RoleType)RoleDeterminer.RoleDeterminate();

        if (role != RoleType.Center)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Restriction");
        }
        IUserBL centerUserBL = new CenterUserBL();

        InModel.User.UserName = InModell.User.NationalCode;
        InModel.User.Password = InModell.User.PersonalCode;
        bool confirmedBL = centerUserBL.AddUser(InModel.User);

       _msgList.Add(new Message() { MsgType = MessageType.Success, MsgContent =         MessageProvider.GetMessage(MessageContent.Submit_Success_NewUser) });
        ViewBag.Message = _msgList;

        return View();
        }

        else
        {
         return View(InModel);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'd argue the *best* approach would be the first option, actually. With your recommended best approach if the OP hits F5 they will be prompted to re-submit the request. The first approach follows the PRG pattern.

Comment: removed best tag...:)